# Is it possible to process two microphones input in real time using DSP System Toolbox(MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, noise-reduction

I have been trying to implement an Active Noise Cancellation(ANC) system using the Digital System Processing system toolbox. I have used the `dsp.AudioRecorder` and `dsp.AudioPlayer` as well. This is my initialization code:

```
mic_reference = dsp.AudioRecorder('NumChannels',1);
mic_reference.DeviceName='ASIO4ALL v2'; 
mic_error = dsp.AudioRecorder('NumChannels',1);
mic_error.DeviceName='ASIO4ALL v2';
sink1_2 = dsp.AudioPlayer;
sink1_2.DeviceName='ASIO4ALL v2';
```

where I call `step(frame)` for each of the microphones. I am getting an error saying that

> Error using AudioRecorder/step A given audio device may only be opened once.

Is it the limitation of the DSP system toolbox to be able to operate on only one audio recorder device at a time, or is it possible to use two audio recorder devices at a time?

There is a provision for multichannel processing of the same audio device, but how to process the audio from two independent devices in real time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charansai,

This is not a limitation of the DSP System Toolbox but the behaviour of the ASIO drivers. ASIO drivers grant exclusive access to an application for playback or recording. So the second object is attempting to re-use the same device for recording and hence the error.

In your case, if your reference signal is channel 1 and error signal is channel 2, you need to record 2 channels of data instead of using two recorder objects.

```
har = dsp.AudioRecorder('NumChannels', 2);
har.DeviceName = 'ASIO4ALL v2';
hap = dsp.AudioPlayer;
hap.DeviceName = 'ASIO4ALL v2';
data = step(har);
refData = data(:, 1);
errData = data(:, 2);
outData = doSomething(refData, errData);
step(hap, outData);
```

Hope this helps.

Dinesh

Comment: Thank You Dinesh. I think it is the problem with ASIO drivers. Now I changed the audio driver to 'Direct Sound' and can be able to give two different device names for two microphones and process both of them simultaneously. So, it is not true that DSP system toolbox can't process two audio inputs. But how to control the ASIO driver from granting exclusive access( given that it is stable driver than 'Direct Sound') ?

Comment: and    can you explain how to map two channels ( left channel to one device and right channel to other device). I could not understand what you are doing in the above code, you are taking one audio recorder( microphone) and processing its two stereo(left and right) inputs as two data(ref,err). Where is the second microphone in the picture ?

Comment: DirectSound and ASIO have different purposes. ASIO is primarily used in low-latency applications whereas DirectSound. DirectSound creates a virtual device layer that applications talk to. Each application talks to this virtual layer and not the actual physical device. During playback, if two apps try to play two sounds to the same output, DirectSound will take care of the mixing which increases latency.

So, the choice of the driver model depends upon the purpose of your application

Comment: I am not entirely clear on how many signals you are trying to record. If you are using two recorder objects, I am assuming that you need two input signals.

Comment: With the DirectSound I have audio latency of 1.2 sec, with out any extra processing just 'dspStreamingPassthrough'. How much can I reduce with ASIO ?? Is converting the script to MEX file going to affect the processing time ?

Answer (score 0):

When you record your signal, you should be recording it from 2 microphones (each called a channel/observation - i.e left and right channel), and you should combine these two observations together into one stream before passing it to Matlab, you should only pass 1 dual channel signal input into the dsp AudioRecorder toolbox - it does not accept two sources I don't think. When you read in the data, it should be a matrix of 2 vectors (given that you specified 2 channels in the AudioRecorder setup).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Actually in Acitve Noise Cancellation, I will use two different microphones (reference and error ) and one loudspeaker, all of these should be processed in real time. I am not talking about two channel(left and right) processing. So, it is not possible to use dsp AudioRecorder to process two microphones and one loudspeaker in real time.. ! 
Is there any possibility to use single Audio Recorder to process one frame from one microphone(reference) and the next frame from other microphone(error). So, I can process the data with some lag.

Comment: Do you have two stereo microphones? Otherwise you can connect one microphone to the left channel, the other to the right channel, and read both at the same time.

Comment: it is as @hbaderts said, both microphones should be forming one stream of real-time data.

Comment: @hbaderts how to map channels to different audio devices?? ( left channel to one microphone and right channel to other microphone ) ?

Comment: @GameOfThrows now I changed audio driver from ASIO to 'Direct Sound' and can be able to identify the two Audiorecorder objects by two different names and process them online. !

Comment: @charansai: If you have two microphones, you can connect them to different channels on the same sound-card which will be picked up as a single device. So you can record 2 channels on this device in which case you need only 1 dsp.AudioRecorder object.